# Connection to PC and TFS

Tags: tfs, windows-10, connection

I have some issues with connection to the our Team Foundation Server.

Lets say i have computer with TFS set on it named `Computer 1`. After I changed the **Homegroup** of `Computer 1` all of the computers in the office **lost connection to** `Computer 1`.

The configuration about the TFS in inbound firewall connections are correct. The IIS is set correctly. I can **ping the IP** of `Computer 1` from **any computer in the office correctly** but anyway no one can connect to the TFS.

I tried to reach the TFS from `Computer 1` and it is working correctly so something about connection to `Computer 1` is going wrong.  Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Could you open the tfs web portal on any other computer  in the office?

Comment: If i could there is no logic visual studio to tell me that i can't connect to the tfs. The firewall was making some issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, disable the firewall settings and try the connection again.

Since you can ping the `Computer 1` successfully, also try to use the IP address directly in Visual Studio such as `http://10.168.175.175:8080/tfs` to connect TFS.
[image]

Comment: Actually 5 minutes after i asked the question i tried to disable the firewall and all started work correctly. Sorry i didn't answer earlier.